# java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table/View does not exist

Tags: mysql, sql, jdbc

I downloaded a script from the internet - it's a JSF registration app that will sign you up or log you in using a MySQL server. I've been playing with this piece of code for 3 hours but I'm a beginner so I don't really know what the problem is. Here it is:

```
if (firstName != null) {  
        PreparedStatement ps = null;  
        Connection con = null;  
        try {  
            if (ds != null) {  
                con = ds.getConnection();  
                System.out.println();

                if (con != null) {  
                    String sql = "INSERT INTO userdata(firstname, password, lastname, email) VALUES(?,?,?,?)";  
                    ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);  
                    ps.setString(1, firstName);  
                    ps.setString(2, password);  
                    ps.setString(3, lastName);  
                    ps.setString(4, email);  
                    i = ps.executeUpdate();  
                    System.out.println("Data Added Successfully");  
                }  
            }  
        } catch (Exception e) {  
            System.out.println(e);  
        } finally {  
            try {  
                con.close();  
                ps.close();  
            } catch (Exception e) {  
                e.printStackTrace();  
            }  
        }  
    }
```

It keeps saying that there is an error, and this is what I get from the console:

> Info:   java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table/View **'userdata'**
>   does not exist.

The table IS there. I've tried 2 different MySQL servers and some properties changes as well, but nothing seems to help.

Comment: Do you have table/view names `APP.PICOVINA`?

Comment: Well, if the table name is in czech, it could be a hint...in czech it means "bullshit" :))

Comment: lad2025 - yes i do
James - it is in Slovakian, i was so pissed off at the end that i named it this way :)

Comment: Are you connecting to the right database? Does the user you use for connecting have access to this table?

Comment: Mark: yes, i tried some printlines, the driver is loaded successfully and the connection to the DB is established... im connecting as a root

Answer (score 0):

I am nearly sure that you have a dot in the Table name. So MySQL interprets this an SCHEMA APP and as Table name PICOVINA and this wars not existing. So quote your complete table name with backticks.

```
MariaDB [tmp]> show tables like 'APP%';
+----------------------+
| Tables_in_tmp (APP%) |
+----------------------+
| APP.PICOVINA         |
+----------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [tmp]> select * from APP.PICOVINA;
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'app.picovina' doesn't exist
MariaDB [tmp]>
MariaDB [tmp]>
MariaDB [tmp]> select * from `APP.PICOVINA`;
Empty set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [tmp]>
```

Comment: Sorry about the old post, it wasnt supposed to be PICOVINA but USERNAME ------
I tried to do it this way, it doesnt work as well. I tried: 
INSERT INTO username(...) VALUES (...) ---then 
INSERT INTO 'APP.username'(...) VALUES (...) ---and then
INSERT INTO username VALUES (...) ---

non of these works